# How to implement DIAL protocol in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, protocols

I want to implement DIAL protocol for web app as 2nd screen in react js or pure javascript. How can I achieve this?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From React perspective (Client) the communication with DIAL is accomplished through simple REST calls to the DIAL server.

For any info about the protocol usage from server-side and client-side perspective, please refer to the [Netflix reference](https://github.com/Netflix/dial-reference)

> The DIAL client uses CURL to send HTTP REST commands to the DIAL
>   server, so to build the client, you need to ensure that the CURL
>   dependencies are defined properly.

Notice that the client available in the Netflix repo is a C++ console application.